# Cannot build and run a C program in Code::Blocks

Tags: c

I'm using Code:Blocks IDE on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I created a console application project and used GNU complier to build and run this simple `Hello World!` message:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

However, upon clicking `Build and Run` it gave me this message

```
File             | Message
.................|..........................
obj/Debug/main.o | No such file or directory
```

Could this be a bug or I'm simply missing some plugins? Any help is welcomed.

Comment: Post your project file.  It has the extension .cbp

Comment: did you install also gcc and g++?

Comment: I checked and yes, I do have both gcc and g++